# Enable and disable TextBox with a checkbox in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, textbox

I've 6 TextBox and 6 CheckBox. Now I want to disable the TextBox1 with a CheckBox1 and reactivate it with the Same CheckBox. 
How a can do it?

Edit1 15.55 14/02/2013

I have done so to solve my problem!

> `Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
>           
> If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
>               
> TextBox1.Enabled = False
>           
> ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
>               
> TextBox1.Enabled = True
>           End If
>       End Sub` `

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I don't know what to do! I found this http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/17383-activating-deactivating-textbox-checkbox-solved.html but I doesn't work!

Comment: We are happy to help beginners here, but in order to learn programming, you need to get a good book for beginners and start there.  The question and answer format of this site isn't an ideal way to learn the basics.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner, I know it. I will find a good book!

Comment: Once you run into a problem that you can't figure out on your own, please come back, we'd love to help!

Comment: No problem, I will return when I will need it! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work, just add more for the other check boxes

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            TextBox1.Enabled = True
        Else
            TextBox1.Enabled = False
        End If
End Sub
```

What this does: if checkbox1 is check, the checked_changed event fires and the code inside is ran. The if statement looks to see if the checkbox is checked or not. If it  is checked, then  it sets the textbox1 to enabled, if not it sets it to disabled. Be sure to set the enabled property to either enabled or disabled when you create your program. If you want it to be enabled from the start, that is the default....otherwise set it to disabled in its properties view.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    TextBox1.Enabled = CheckBox1.Checked
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial below.  After, look at the checkbox control's events and choose the most fitting one.  The property you will be changing on the textbox is **Enabled**.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4PbUryXqZ50

Answer (score 0):

This works if you have a layer built in that you can send objects behind (therefore hide things).  I use this as a way to make text boxes and other items appear and disappear depending on other selections.

```
Private Sub checkbox_Click()
    If (checkbox = True) Then

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("textbox").ZOrder msoSendToFront
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("textbox").ZOrder msoSendToFront

    Else

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("textbox").ZOrder msoSendToBack
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("textbox").ZOrder msoSendToBack

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        TextBox1.Enabled = False

        If Not TextBox1.Enabled Then
            TextBox1.BackColor = Color.White
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
            TextBox1.Enabled = True
        Else
            TextBox1.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Okay then Jean-Francois... I looked at one website and tried that code. But found it only worked one way which was opposite to what I wanted. So I did some more research and found the first part ( the first private sub). It didnt work alone so I combined them. Im not much of a coder yet. Just started out of need. Thanks. Better?